# Confusion on Linked Lists

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list

I read this code written in the programming principles and practice using c++ book.

```
struct Link {
string value;
Link* prev;
Link* succ;
Link(const string& v, Link* p = nullptr, Link* s = nullptr)
: value{v}, prev{p}, succ{s} { }
};
```

I like his approach to teaching starting from an empty shell and working his way up(By his/he i mean the author of the book).
So on his first attempt at building a list(of Norse gods ), he did this:

```
Link* norse_gods = new Link{"Thor",nullptr,nullptr};
norse_gods = new Link{"Odin",nullptr,norse_gods};
norse_gods–>succ–>prev = norse_gods;
norse_gods = new Link{"Freia",nullptr,norse_gods};
norse_gods–>succ–>prev = norse_gods;
```

The confusion I have is on the fact that he had to explicitly state this:

```
norse_gods–>succ–>prev = norse_gods;
```

as seen on the third and fifth lines.

I was thinking adding items without explicitly stating that line of code in between each addition will also work.
i.e:

```
Link* norse_gods = new Link{"Thor",nullptr,nullptr};
norse_gods = new Link{"Odin",nullptr,norse_gods};
norse_gods = new Link{"Freia",nullptr,norse_gods};
```

Is my state of thinking wrong? And why does that line( `norse_gods–>succ–>prev = norse_gods;`) have to be explicitly added to the code

Comment: Work it out on paper. See what the linked list looks like if you omit the line `norse_gods–>succ–>prev = norse_gods;`

Comment: @RaymondChen Because of the way the constructor is written, i see it as a repetition to declare ` norse_gods–>succ–>prev = norse_gods; `

Comment: Before line 3, `norse_gods–>succ` was created with `new Link{"Thor",nullptr,nullptr};`, which set `norse_gods–>succ–>prev == nullptr`. If you don't assign to it, it'll remain `nullptr`.

Comment: @TosinAI Every new norse god is created such that they are the head of the list. The new god's succ and prev is good, but not the old one that was once the head. It needs to have its prev to the newly created god that is now the head. If the lines in question were omitted, all of the norse gods would have `nullptr` as their `prev`.

Comment: Ideally, your list would have an `insert(string name, Link *pred, Link *succ)`  function which calls the proper `Link` constructor and hides the List bookkeeping operations so that the user code doesn't have to do it. In fact, if that `insert()` is a member or friend function, the constructor can become protected or private because the user code likely neither needs nor wants to construct one explicitly. That `insert()` function would also handle insertions in the middle or end of the list properly.

Comment: Even more ideally, the `Link` type would not be exposed at all; instead, the list user interface would be iterator based, like `std::list`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us say that `A <--> B` says `A->succ == B` and `B->prev == A`. After line 1 you have:

`norse_gods == Thor`

After line 2 you have:

`norse_gods == Odin ---> Thor`

The problem here is that `Odin->succ == Thor` but `Thor->prev == nullptr`. Because every element in the list has a pointer to its previous and successor element this is a doubly-linked list intended to be traversed in both directions, but right now it can only be traversed in one (left to right). This is corrected by making `Thor->prev == Odin`. Since `Odin->succ == Thor` and `norse_gods == Odin` we can access and change `Thor->prev` that way in the line `norse_gods->succ->prev = norse_gods;`. After that you have:

`norse_gods == Odin <--> Thor`